# How to add a horizontal scrollbar to access overflow columns in Material-UI Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling, react-component, material-table

I have a table with a fixed table layout in my react app where i'm using MaterialTable (found here [material-table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/))
component in **material-ui**.

The problem comes when in mobile size,i want to have a horizontal scrollbar to view overflow columns. At the moment, i added `wordWrap: "break-word"` just to make the table fit properly but i want to replace that with a single horizontal bar. Kindly offer an assistance.

```
return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Editable Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      options={{
        rowStyle: {
          wordWrap: "break-word",
        },
        padding: "dense",
        tableLayout: "fixed",
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        exportButton: true,
        draggable: true,
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: (newData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState((prevState) => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.push(newData);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              if (oldData) {
                setState((prevState) => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState((prevState) => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
      }}
    />
  );
```

The visual illustration of the problem is shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the `tableLayout` as **auto** (not fixed)

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-mobile-device-overflow-fix-t537r?file=/src/index.js)

**Sample Code**

```js
<MaterialTable
      title="Editable Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      options={{
        rowStyle: {
          wordWrap: "break-word",
        },
        padding: "dense",
        tableLayout: "auto", //<-----here
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        exportButton: true,
        draggable: true,
     .....
```

Comment: This is not really efficient seeing that it adds scrollbar to each cell. I would like the table to have **one scrollbar** at the bottom that caters for all overflow columns.

Comment: I see - np - i have updated the answer... pls chk .. I have updated the code in the codesandbox demo .. use the same link (just refresh the browser)

Comment: Sadly setting ```tableLayout: "auto",``` doesn't work with that particular table that i used. It only works with the table you chose not the one i provided. I could switch to the version of table you used but it has limited features. It does not have the actions column that has **add**, **update** and **delete** rows actions, which is what i need.

Comment: can you please put your code in codesandbox and share the link..

Comment: Sandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-napier-r977n?file=/src/App.js). The problem i'm having with sandbox and also the reason now i understand why your way worked is in a wierd way the code in sandbox works but not in a react app. Try building a react app then add the table and find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
overflow-x : auto
```

to parent component

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent's div(s) width.